# Web application hosted on JBoss EAP 7.4.11 with SSO for authentication is causing web pages to not be cached

Tags: servlets, jboss, single-sign-on, cache-control

I have a web application which is hosted on JBoss 7.4.11 with SSO as authentication mechanism, the website is working as expected however all there is no caching happening. All web pages are always fetched causing optimization issues for testing. The same website when deployed with BuiltIn authentication provides with caching. Is there any setting that I need to set when working with SSO and Jboss to allow caching of web pages.

In the standalone.xml I added an attribute to the default servlet configuration as follows:
<servlet-container name="default" **disable-caching-for-secured-pages="false"**>

which is not working. Any help would be appreciated